# push UISplitViewController upon login using swift

Tags: swift, ios8

I am trying to push UISplitViewController upon button click but not having much luck. When I run the app I have the FirstViewController which is on the storyboard as the intial screen which only have a button, upon button click I want to push UISplitViewController, below is the code I am using upon button click, can someone please suggest what I am doing wrong, thnx

```
@IBAction func launchSplitView(sender: AnyObject)
{
    let leftVC = LeftViewController()
    let detailVC = RightViewDetailController()
    let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()
    //splitViewController.delegate = //UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [leftVC,detailVC];
    //splitViewController.delegate = self
    splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.AllVisible

    window?.rootViewController = splitViewController
  //  window.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what is actually happening when you run your app.

Comment: It does not go anywhere just stays on the same screen

Comment: is the SplitViewController in a separate ViewController that needs a segue or are you trying to make it appear on the initial ViewController?

Comment: SplitViewController is a separate object on storyboard, it was dragged on to storyboard as "Split View Controller" from the bottom right view object library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now this is the solution I found
=>I was able to launch through segue but not programmatically

When I programmatically launch using "launchSplitView function", I have issues with TableviewController which is the first view controller in split view but when I use segue it works. Not sure if its a bug or what. Segue is good enough for now.

Comment: I have the same implementation  One VIewController with a label on it  --> then a SplitViewController. However, when I try to drag a segue from the ViewController to the SplitViewController nothing happens, no segue option pops up. Can you post a demo or give more details.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `window?.rootViewController` because your storyboard is the `rootViewController` instead you should use `presentViewController`

```
@IBAction func launchSplitView(sender: AnyObject){
    let leftVC = LeftViewController()
    let detailVC = RightViewDetailController()
    let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()

    splitViewController.viewControllers = [leftVC,detailVC];

    self.presentViewController(splitViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```